# Django annotate() optimization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Supposing a ManyToMany relationship between A and B.
The following request is taking too much time to execute when some A instances have > 500 b.

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = A.objects.all()

        qs = qs.annotate(
            not_confirmed=Count('b', filter=Q(b__removed__isnull=True, b__confirmed__isnull=True)),
            confirmed=Count('b', filter=Q(b__removed__isnull=True, b__confirmed__isnull=False)),
        )

        return qs
```

Do you have an idea how to optimize this ?

I tried prefetch_related, or using `b = B.objects.filter(removed__isnull=True)` to do the request only once but not relevent...
I would like my request time < 30 sec

Comment: You can use [`indexes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/indexes/) to speed up the query.